# nested try catch block not working as expected

Tags: php, class, exception

I have the following function that is not working as expected. An error is thrown in the nested try block (containing `zippyConstructor`), however instead of the error going to that respective catch block with the `unlink` commands the error goes to the outer catch block circumventing some of the built in safe guards (e.g. removing a bad file). Is there something I am missing with regards to nested try catch blocks?

```
public function doBackup($rethrow = false)
{
    try {

        $filename = 'dbbackup_' . date(str_replace('-', '.', DATE_FORMAT) . '_H_i_s');

        $tables = $this->tablesToBackup();

        $data = $this->mysqlDump($tables);

        $this->createSaveDir();

        $sqlFile = $this->dir_sql . $filename . '.sql';
        $handle = @fopen($sqlFile, 'w+');

        if (!$handle) {
            throw new Exception ("Could not open: {$sqlFile}");
        }

        if (@fwrite($handle, $data) === FALSE) {
            throw new Exception ("Could write: {$sqlFile}");
        }

        try {

            $this->zippyConstructor($this->dir_files . $filename . '.zip', $this->folders_to_backup, $sqlFile);

            @fclose($handle);

            if (!$rethrow) {
                $this->msg->add('s', "Backup {$filename} successfully created.");
            }

        } catch (ZipException $e) {

            @fclose($handle);

            // remove corrupted files
            is_file($sqlFile) ? @unlink($sqlFile) : '';
            is_file($this->dir_files . $filename . '.zip') ? @unlink($this->dir_files . $filename . '.zip') : '';

            if ($rethrow) {
                throw $e;
            } else {
                $this->msg->add('e', 'Inner_Catch Backup failed: <br>' . $e->getMessage());
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {

        @fclose($handle);

        if ($rethrow) {
            throw $e;
        } else {
            $this->msg->add('e', 'Outer_Catch Backup failed: <br>' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure zippyConstructor is throwing a ZipException? If it is throwing something else, the inner catch will pass it on up.